# Oracle Nested Select doesn't allow order by clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a requirement to fetch latest record from LEAD_REASSIGNMENT_TABLE LRD based on KSA.LEAD_ID = LRD.LEAD_ID.
Query is as follows ,

```
SELECT
KSA.LEAD_ID  AS "leadId",
KSA.CREATED_ON      AS "createdOn",
KSA.FIRST_NAME      AS "firstName",
KSA.LAST_NAME       AS "lastName",
KSA.CRN             AS "crn" ,
KSA.MOBILE_NO        AS "mobileNumber",
KSA.BRANCH_CODE     AS "lpdBranchCode", 

( SELECT T.DESCRIPTION FROM TERRITORY T WHERE T.ID IN 
    (
        SELECT STM.TERRITORY_ID FROM SPOKE_TERRITORY_MAPPING STM
         WHERE STM.SPOKE_CODE IN (SELECT SM.ID FROM SPOKE_MASTER SM WHERE SM.SPOKE_CODE=KSA.BRANCH_CODE AND SM.DELETE_FLAG='F') AND STM.DELETE_FLAG='F' 
     ) AND T.DELETE_FLAG='F' AND ROWNUM<=1
)  AS "lpdSubLocation" ,

(select lrd.LEAD_NEW_ASSIGNED_USER  from LEAD_REASSIGNMENT_DETAILS lrd
where lrd.LEAD_ID = KSA.LEAD_ID and rownum <=1
) AS "NEW_ASSIGNED_USER"


FROM KSA_LEAD_DATA KSA
   LEFT JOIN LEAD_PROSPECT_DETAILS LPD
ON KSA.LEAD_ID = LPD.KSA_LEAD_ID 
LEFT JOIN ENTITY_TYPE_MAPPING ETM
ON LPD.LOAN_STATUS = ETM.ENTITY_CODE 
    WHERE KSA.DELETE_FLAG IS NOT NULL 
  ORDER BY KSA.LEAD_ID desc ;
```

Now when in the select i do

```
(select lrd.LEAD_NEW_ASSIGNED_USER  from LEAD_REASSIGNMENT_DETAILS lrd
where lrd.LEAD_ID = KSA.LEAD_ID and rownum <=1
ORDER BY LRD.MODIFIED_ON) AS "NEW_ASSIGNED_USER"
```

I get ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  **"missing right parenthesis"** Error

But when i use select **without order by clause** it works fine

```
(select lrd.LEAD_NEW_ASSIGNED_USER  from LEAD_REASSIGNMENT_DETAILS lrd
where lrd.LEAD_ID = KSA.LEAD_ID and rownum <=1
) AS "NEW_ASSIGNED_USER"
```

If i use select without order by clause it wont guarantee me that i ll fetch the latest record from LEAD_REASSIGNMENT_TABLE.

**NOTE**
LEAD_REASSIGNMENT_TABLE contains 3-4 records with same lead_id 
so i am selecting the latest record based on modified_on timestamp.

How should i use Order by clause inside nested select.?

Answer (score 0):

I don't like correlated subqueries, not within the `SELECT` statement.

Anyway: if you rewrite that piece of code as below, I guess it should work.

```
(SELECT lrd.LEAD_NEW_ASSIGNED_USER
  FROM LEAD_REASSIGNMENT_DETAILS lrd
 WHERE     lrd.LEAD_ID = KSA.LEAD_ID
       AND lrd.modified_on = (SELECT MAX (lrd1.modified_on)
                                FROM LEAD_REASSIGNMENT_DETAILS lrd1
                               WHERE lrd1.lead_id = lrd.lead_id)) AS "NEW_ASSIGNED_USER"
```

Comment: `I don't like correlated subqueries, not within the SELECT statement.` I didn't use to like them either, but scalar subqueries can be cached, meaning that if the correlation is repeated, you can gain a benefit from using them. If they're correlated on a primary/unique key, there's little benefit to them.